# Problem with if-else statement in React - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with Conditional Statements in my React app.
I am using API with recipes and want to show recipes when type something in input. And also want to display "Recipe not found..." when nothing is found.
So problem is that app ignore first if statement every time.
When I search pizza, it displays "Recipe not found.."

```
function Searched() {
    const [searchedRecepies, setSearchedRecepies] = useState([]);
    let params = useParams();
    
    const getSearched = async (name) => {
        const data = await fetch (`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=${name}&number=80&apiKey=**********`)
        const recipes = await data.json();
        setSearchedRecepies(recipes.results);
      };

    useEffect(() => {
        getSearched(params.search); 
    }, [params.search])

    
      if(searchedRecepies.totalResults > 0){
        return (
          <div className='searchedSection'>
            <h1>Results for <strong>"{params.search}"</strong></h1>
            <div className='gridSearched'>
              {searchedRecepies.map((item) => {
                return(
                  <div className='gridSearchedCard' key={item.id}>
                    <Link to={'/recipe/' + item.id}>
                      <img src={item.image} alt={item.title} />
                      <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                )
              })} 
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
      else {
        return (
          <div className='searchedSection'>
            <h1>Results for <strong>"{params.search}"</strong></h1>
            <h1 className='notFound'>Recipe not found..</h1>
          </div>  
        )        
      }   
}
```

So API returns this:

```
{"results":[{"id":656329,"title":"Pizza bites with pumpkin","image":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/656329-312x231.jpg","imageType":"jpg"},{"id":680975,"title":"BLT Pizza","image":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/680975-312x231.jpg","imageType":"jpg"},{"id":663136,"title":"Thai Pizza","image":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/663136-312x231.jpg","imageType":"jpg"},{"id":716300,"title":"Plantain Pizza","image":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716300-312x231.jpg","imageType":"jpg"},{"id":665769,"title":"Zucchini Pizza Boats","image":"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/665769-312x231.jpg","imageType":"jpg"}],"offset":0,"number":5,"**totalResults**":37}
```

I have the same problem when I am trying to make app to return "Server error.." when server is offline or when I reach API limit. else if(searchedRecepies.code == 402) also not working as it should and really can not detect where is the problem.

In that case, API returns this:

{"status":"failure", "code":402,"message":"Your daily points limit of 150 has been reached. Please upgrade your plan to continue using the API."}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well `getSearched()` is an asynchronous function. The searched recipes won't be available until the HTTP request is complete.

Comment: Side note: it doesn't look like it's affecting anything atm but you may want to sort out the spelling of `searchedRecepies` and `setSearchedRecepies` => `searchedRecipes` and `setSearchedRecipes`. It may trip you up at some point.

Comment: You stored `recipes.results` in the state.  However you didn't store `recipes.totalResults`, since that is not inside `recipes.results`.

Comment: Note also you're initialising the state as an array but according to this line `if (searchedRecepies.totalResults > 0)` the state is an object. If the state is an array of objects this would more likely be `if (searchedRecepies.length)`.